# Pulling Multiple Columns from Different Sheets into Single Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have 50 sheets representing 50 states in a single Spreadsheet, and of those states, I'm trying to consolidate from an input column (Col4 on all sheets, Column 'City' formatted like this: 'Austin, TX') into a single index column to pull from to build a City-plotted map. (I'm using Marker Maps in Google Sheets for this).

However, I keep running into errors trying to accomplish this task.

I've used `=QUERY()` to pull in 2 sheets (2 sheets to make it easy).

```
=QUERY({AL!D2:D10; AK!D2:D10},"SELECT * WHERE Col4 > 0")
```

However, I get a

> 'Query Completed with an empty output' Error.

```
=QUERY({AL!D2:D10; AK!D2:D10},"SELECT *")
```

Works, but I'm only getting the AL city results pulled in, 'Auburn, AL' but no 'Anchorage, AK'.

I've tried varying Select statements to see if it would work, but I cannot get more than a single sheet's Column pulled in.

If anyone has any better suggestions on how to do this, or have an idea why I'm receiving errors or doing it wrong, please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it like this:

```
=QUERY({AL!D2:D10; AK!D2:D10}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```